# How can I read the contents of an URL with Transcrypt? Where is urlopen() located?

Tags: python, url, urlopen, transcrypt

In Transcrypt I try to read JSON data from a URL, so I try:

```
import urllib.request    
data = urllib.request.urlopen(data_url)
```

But I get the error "Import error, can't find [...] urllib.request". So `urllib.request` doesn't seem to be support; strangely though the top-level `import urllib` works, but with this I do not get to the `urlopen()` function...

Any idea where `urlopen()` is located in Transcrypt? Or is there another way to retrieve URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Transcrypt has the Python urllib library available.  You will need to use a corresponding JavaScript library instead.  I prefer axios, but you can also just use the built in XMLHttpRequest() or window.fetch()

Here is a Python function you can incorporate that uses window.fetch():

```
def fetch(url, callback):
    def check_response(response):
        if response.status != 200:
            console.error('Fetch error - Status Code: ' + response.status)
            return None
        return response.json()

    prom = window.fetch(url)
    resp = prom.then(check_response)
    resp.then(callback)
    prom.catch(console.error)
```

Just call this fetch function from your Python code and pass in the URL and a callback to utilize the response after it is received.

Comment: Thanks @JohnS. Yep, I guess that's the way to go. I just have used jQuery. Strange though that `import urllib` does _not_ give an error, while `import urllib.requests` _does_...

Comment: That works too.  Personally I prefer to keep code in the Python realm as much as possible.  It keeps the linter happier as well as my brain.  Also with jQuery you'll need to escape the $ using `__pragma__('alias', 'S', '$')`